# MDX: add dimension in filter but also show in rows

Tags: filter, mdx

I have a simple MDX query that filters data to one of two Status values:

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY
  { [confidentialstring].Members }
ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY
  { [APMWORDER].[LEVEL01].Members *
    [APMSTDOPR].[LEVEL01].Members *
    [AWOUSTAT].[LEVEL01].Members *
    [ANOTIFCTN].[LEVEL01].Members
}
ON ROWS
FROM   [APM_CP002/APM_CP002_QX006]
WHERE { ( [AWOUSTAT].[E0001] ), ( [AWOUSTAT].[E0002] ) }
```

But I also need [AWOUSTAT] in my table, to see which status value is actually applicable.

However MDX throws an error if I add it: 'You may not use the same dimension on different axes'. I understand this in principle but not in this application ('filter' is not an axis to me...)

How can I resolve this, without having to create two queries?

Thanx!

Comment: Can you post your entire query?

Comment: I'm not sure it helps but I edited my question to show the full query.
It throws the error if I include [AWOUSTAT].[LEVEL01].Members *
but runs fine if I don't - yet how do I know the actual STAT values if I can't?

Comment: @vldmrrdjcc did this edit help? Any ideas?

Comment: Please, see my reply, check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot have the same dimension on rows and in where clause, and you want to see [AWOUSTAT].[E0001]] ,  [AWOUSTAT].[E0002] , in your table, I think you could try something like this to start:

```
    SELECT
    NON EMPTY
      { [confidentialstring].Members }
    ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY
      { ( [AWOUSTAT].[E0001]] ), ( [AWOUSTAT].[E0002] ) }
    ON ROWS
    FROM   [APM_CP002/APM_CP002_QX006]
```

Answer (score 0):

A common technique is to replace the `WHERE` clause with a `FROM` clause.

Sample using adventure works:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Order Count]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {[Date].[Day of Month].[Day of Month].ALLMEMBERS}
   ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {[Date].[Fiscal Year].&[2011]} ON COLUMNS
  FROM [Adventure Works]
)
```

In the above example, it is equivalent to having a WHERE clause of the `Fiscal Year = 2011`.

You can see a similar output, whenever you use the SSMS Cube Browser to build queries.

[image]

It may look strange to replace `WHERE` with `FROM`, BUT, in the in most cases with the Cube, it does provide the required output.